# javascript not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a page.  In that page's header i have all of my javascript.  In the pages body i have a link that calls an ajax http request (i use long hand xhr not jquery) and that request pulls a php form on to my page.

That form has some select dropdowns that are formatted/styled using jquery.  The problem i am having is that when i put the form directly in the page the select is formated fine on page load.  But when i remove the form from the page and pull it in using ajax it is as if the javascript is not loading.

So the javascript is loading when the page loads but when i pull in the php form onto the page via ajax the javascript is not working.  the select dropdown is not formated/styled.  It's almost like the javascript needs to reload or something.

I am not using jquery to make the call.  I am just using long hand ajax.

```
function getPage(str)
 {
 if (str=="")
   {
   document.getElementById("center").innerHTML="";
   return;
   } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("center").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","xhr_php/get_page.php?page="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jquery styling script runs, then it is done.  If you want it to run again after your ajax call, put it in a function and call the function on success.

```
function dostuff() 
{
    $('selector').css('var', 'val');
}
```

The success case is when status==200 and readyState==4, fire your js css tweaks in there after you've inserted the HTML response.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("center").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        dostuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of this using my code above.  I have been searching for an "on success" example for hours now and can't find one.  All i keep finding is jquery stuff and i am nto using a jquery afax function i am using long hand.  See my ajax above. thank you.

Comment: Oh, that's a standard part of your AJAX call.  I'll put it in the answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

in the original form, are the select's formatted using a script that runs on page load? if so, that's your problem. loading the form through ajax /after/ page load means that the onload scripts will not affect the selects. you need to run the scripts after the form has been loaded.

Comment: add it in the onSuccess event of the Ajax call. most jQuery tutorials will show you how to do that

Comment: please see my ajax below.  I am not using jquery.

Comment: sorry wouldn't let me answer my own q so please see my post above, i have added the ajax.  Please let m know where i put the onSuccess functionality.

Comment: in the section where you put this: `document.getElementById("center").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;`

Comment: how would i write an onSuccess function there.  I have goodgled onsuccess for ajax and can't find much at all.  thanks.

Comment: that section I pointed out /is/ the onSuccess function... you have the onreadystatechange, and in that, you check to see if it's successful (onSuccess), and then you are putting your form in place. put your select formatting code after that.

Comment: Don't mean to draw out a conversation since that is apparently against the rules, but can you post an example based on my code above.  I have been working on this one issue since 7am its now 4pm and i still do not have a solution. I am very new to ajax.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I'd say you need to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to attach behaviors to your elements.  If you're applying things like datepicker or something on the php form page, to make that functionality available you'll need to reassign to the elements you pulled in with the XHR in the callback function of your XHR request.